# How to print values of nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

This is my code...

```js
var object = {
  person1: {
    userName: person1,
    passWord: password1
  }
  person2: {
    userName: person2,
    passWord: password2
  }
  person3: {
    userName: person3,
    passWord: password3
  }
}
```

And I want to print all the userName of each person.

expected output...

```js
person1
person2
person3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the object values with `Object.values()` and print out the `userName`

```js
const object = {
  person1: {
    userName: "person1",
    passWord: "password1",
  },
  person2: {
    userName: "person2",
    passWord: "password2",
  },
  person3: {
    userName: "person3",
    passWord: "password3",
  },
}

Object.values(object).forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value.userName)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To work your code properly, you need to change couple of things. Values of `userName & password` should set as `String` since `person1, person2, person3, password1, password2, password3` is undefined here.

```js
var object = {
  person1: {
    userName: "person1",
    passWord: "password1"
  },
  person2: {
    userName: "person2",
    passWord: "password2"
  },
  person3: {
    userName: "person3",
    passWord: "password3"
  }
}

for(let person in object) {
  console.log(object[person]['userName'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let object = {
  person1: {
    userName: 'person1',
    passWord: 'password1'
  },
  person2: {
    userName: 'person2',
    passWord: 'password2'
  },
  person3: {
    userName: 'person3',
    passWord: 'password3'
  }
}

for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(object)) {
  console.log(object[key].userName);
}
```